# math array homework issue coding javascript?

Tags: javascript, math

this is what i have but i need to record the problems that are wrong and have the user answer them until there right, keep prompting the user for the problem until its right this was a 4 part problem and part3 is to have the same problem repeat until its completed

ex.(7+1=6) repeat(7+1=4) repeat (7+1=8) next problem
the user has to complete 5 problems and they have to be correct

```
    <html>
    <script>
var file=0;
var fileIndex=new Array();
var user=prompt("what is "+a+" + "+b);
var arr=[user,user,user,user,user];
var a=Math.floor(Math.random()*11);
var b=Math.floor(Math.random()*11);
var answer=parseInt(a+b);
var user=prompt("what is "+a+" + "+b);


while (user != answer && file++ != 4) {
fileIndex.push(user);
user = prompt("what is " + a + "+" + b);
 } else {
alert("answer is:" + answer);
 }

}//close for

</script>
```

Comment: Could you provide a little more context? I think you need to be watching for events (aka when the user submits a new answer).

Comment: Please could you edit your question (some punctuation maybe?) to explain what about the array is throwing you off and maybe even indent your code...

Comment: I think you are not using the array "arr".

Answer (score 0):

Update:

```
var a = 1,
    b = 1;

var answer = a + b,
    tick = 0;

var file_index = [], copy;

function randomize() {
    a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11);
    b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11);

    answer = a + b;
}

while (1)
{
    if ((copy = prompt("What is " + a + " + " + " b?", 0)) != answer)
    {
        if (!copy) break;
        file_index.push(copy);
        randomize();
    } else if (tick == 4) {   
        break;
    } else {
        ++tick;
    }
}
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/fxTrn/)

Comment: well its more of i don't know what to do??

Comment: @ChrisMurphy Please see the edit. Increment `file` on each iteration and get rid of the for loop. Just replace it with this code.

Comment: i just rewrote what i had to do

Comment: @ChrisMurphy Your array `[user, user ...]` is also wrong because `user` wasn't defined by the time you did that. Define `arr` *after* you define `user`.

Comment: @ChrisMurphy Yes. Can you explain your assignment more clearly? What I take it you need to do is the loop and prompt the user for the answer to the addition problem. If he gets it wrong, continue looping and prompting him for the answer until his 5 tries are over. When he has exhausted all of his tries, print out the answer. Is this correct?

Comment: the best i can explain is 1)have user answer 5 questions correctly 2)if answer is wrong prompt user to answer the question correctly only end the script if 5/5 are correct @0x499602D2

Comment: @ChrisMurphy Try out my update. It only stops if you get 5 correct.

Comment: when i prompt the problem shows "a+b" not "number+number" i tried modifying it and its kinda getting a pain..

Comment: @ChrisMurphy Change it to `prompt("What is " + a + " + " + " b?", 0)) != answer)`